# Enumeration Program

Tags: python, text-files, nmap

I'm in the process of creating a program that takes an IP address, performs an nmap scan, and takes the output and puts it in a text file. The scan works fine, but I can't seem to figure out why it's not writing anything to the text file.

Here is what I have so far

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    import socket
    import nmap
    import sys
    import io
    from libnmap.parser import NmapParser, NmapParserException
    from libnmap.process import NmapProcess
    from time import sleep
    from os import path

    #Program Banner
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        print(
"""
test
""")
        sys.exit()


#Grab IP Address as argument
if len(sys.argv)==2:
    ip = sys.argv[1]
    print "\n[+] Reading IP Address"


#Function - Pass IP to Nmap then start scanning
print "\n[+] Passing " + ip + " to Nmap..."
print("\n[+] Starting Nmap Scan\n")

def nmap_scan(ip, options):
    parsed = None
    nmproc = NmapProcess(ip, options)
    rc = nmproc.run()
    if rc != 0:
        print("nmap scan failed: {0}".format(nmproc.stderr))

    try:
        parsed = NmapParser.parse(nmproc.stdout)
    except NmapParserException as e:
        print("Exception raised while parsing scan: {0}".format(e.msg))

    return parsed


#Function - Display Nmap scan results
def show_scan(nmap_report):
    for host in nmap_report.hosts:
        if len(host.hostnames):
            tmp_host = host.hostnames.pop()
        else:
            tmp_host = host.address

        print("Host is [ %s ]\n" % str.upper(host.status))
        print("  PORT     STATE         SERVICE")

        for serv in host.services:
            pserv = "{0:>5s}/{1:3s}  {2:12s}  {3}".format(
                    str(serv.port),
                    serv.protocol,
                    serv.state,
                    serv.service)
            if len(serv.banner):
                pserv += " ({0})".format(serv.banner)
            print(pserv)


#Function - Define output text file name & write to file
def createFile(dest):
    name = "Enumerator-Results.txt"

    if not(path.isfile(dest+name)):
        f = open(dest+name,"a+")
        f.write(show_scan(report))
        f.close()    



if __name__ == "__main__":
    report = nmap_scan(ip, "-sV")
    if report:
        destination = "/root/Desktop/"
        createFile(destination)
        show_scan(report)
        print "\nReport Complete!"
    else:
        print("No results returned")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using print statements in your show_scan() function. Instead try passing the file reference to show_scan() and replacing the print() calls with f.write() calls. This would save to file everything you're currently printing to the terminal.

Alternatively you could just change your code so that the show_scan is separate from the f.write().

ie change

```
f.write(show_scan(report))
```

to

```
f.write(report)
```

It depends on whether you want to save the raw output or what you're printing to the screen.

Also you will need to pass the reference of the report to createFile so that it has the report to print ie

```
createFile(destination, report)
```

Just make sure you are always calling f.write() with a string as its parameter.

```
#Function - Define output text file name & write to file
def createFile(dest, report):
    name = "Enumerator-Results.txt"

    if not(path.isfile(dest+name)):
        f = open(dest+name,"a+")
        f.write(report)
        f.close()    



if __name__ == "__main__":
    report = nmap_scan(ip, "-sV")
    if report:
        destination = "/root/Desktop/"
        createFile(destination, report)
        show_scan(report)
        print "\nReport Complete!"
    else:
        print("No results returned")
```

Comment: do you mean this way?

Comment: sorry I'm trying to figure out how to paste the updated code snippet

Comment: def nmap_scan(name):

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to post a reply with a code snippet of what I changed. The site is not much help with that

Comment: I'm not sure why but my post was rejected. It may be because I was trying to post it in your edit because I can't seem to find a way to post updated snippets